# Replacing empty paragraph using preg_replace, whitespace not recognized

Tags: php, regex, encoding

I need to change this:

```
<p> </p>
```

Into this:

```
<p class="notmobile"> </p>
```

on a string. Seems simple, but the following don't work:

```
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/<p> <\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',   $filecontent);
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/^<p> <\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',  $filecontent);
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/<p>\s<\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',  $filecontent);
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/<p>\s+<\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>', $filecontent);
$filecontent  = str_replace('<p> </p>', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',   $filecontent);
```

To make sure I wasn't going crazy, I did a replace on xxx to turn it into yyy which worked just fine. I *think* the problem is my space isn't a normal space as the content is probably that windows character set iso-8859-1 or whatever it is (or it's got confused because we've converted that to utf-8 somewhere along the line..)

Copying and pasting the empty paragraph from chome/firefox didn't work either.

I'm a bit stuck :( Thanks for helping!

**Update: Here's the base64_output, AwMD is a string of 0s which I used to mark the beginning of a string of p's as above.**

AwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA8L3A+DQo8cD7CoDwvcD4NCjxwPsKgPC9wPg0KPHA+wqA8L3A+DQo8cD7CoDwvcD4NCjxwPsKgPC9wPg0KPHA+wqA8L3A+DQo8cD7CoDwvcD4NCjxwPsKgPC9wPg0KPHA+wqA8L3A+DQo8cD7CoDwvcD4NCjxwPsKgPC9wPg0KPHA+wqA8L3A+DQo8cD7CoDwvcD4NCjxwPsKgPC9wPg0KPHA+YmFzZTY0ZW5jb2Rpbmc8L3A+PC9w

**update2: I've found the charater ord values in php are: 194 followed by 160 - eg it's two characters. WEIRD. **

Comment: Can you post the string encoded in some unambiguous format, such as hex or base64 so that we can see exactly what characters it consists of?

Comment: How would I do that? The paragraph is inserted by tinymce in our cms, cms saves the content into a mysql database and then the cms displays the page from the database.

Comment: Your fourth preg_replace is what you want. And more importantly: it's working fine. You might change the `+` into `*` and add the `/ims` flags. Otherwise there is something else in your source text. (Existing attributes in the `<p>` tags for example?)

Comment: To test your theory, you can print each character of the empty paragraph using `ord()`.  Or your editor might support printing the hex value of a character, e.g. in `Vim`, hover over the letter and type `ga`.

Comment: Should it be some other whitespace character, then use `/\p{Z}+/u` to kill it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's indeed the UTF-8 encoding `11000010 10100000` of NBSP `\xA0`. As said earlier, this works:

```
= preg_replace('/<p>\p{Z}*<\/p>/u', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>', $f);
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, I couldn't figure out how to get your regexp in there properly. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace `<p>` with `<p class="notmobile">`?

```
$filecontent = str_replace("<p>", "<p class=\"notmobile\">", $filecontent);
```

Or are you trying to replace *all* pairs of `<p>` tags, regardless of content, with `<p class="notmobile"> </p>`?

---

For tag pairs with only *one* space in between, try replacing it like so:

```
$filecontent = str_replace("<p> </p>", "<p class=\"notmobile\"> </p>", $filecontent);
```

Comment: Because I only want to replace empty paragrahs generated by tinymce with that, not paragraphs with content.

Comment: Then just replace `<p> </p>` with `<p class="notmobile"> </p>`.

Comment: The point was the space wasn't a regular space, it was hex C2A0 (eg two funny characters glued together)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` ASCII code `0xA0, 160`.

Try:

```
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/<p>\xA0<\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',   $filecontent);
```

Comment: You were heading in the right direction. Funny that C2A0 is displayed as just one character.. I wonder what C2 actually is..

Answer (score 0):

```
$filecontent  = preg_replace('/<p>\xC2\xA0<\/p>/', '<p class="notmobile"> </p>',    $filecontent);
```

Easy when you realise nothing is as it seems! Modding up useful answers now.